# Why is my kg/lb conversion returning 0?

Tags: swift, measurement

My function is used to convert between kilograms and pounds. For some unknown reason, the `converted(to:)` method seems to be either returning 0 (which I think is unlikely) or the assignment of the returned value to `liftWeight` isn't working.

```
func convertUnit(liftEvent: LiftEventRepresentable ) -> LiftEventRepresentable {
    let unit = liftEvent.liftWeight.unit.symbol
    switch unit {
    case "kg":
        let weight = liftEvent.liftWeight
        print("Event weight is \(weight)") // 110.0 kg
        let liftWeight = weight.converted(to: .pounds) // this is returning 0 or the assignment isn't working
        print("The new weight is \(liftWeight)") 0.0 lb
        liftEvent.updateWeightLifted(liftWeight.value)
        liftEvent.updateWeightUnit(liftEvent.liftWeight.unit.symbol)
        return liftEvent
    case "lb":

        // I'll finish this case after I get case "kg": working

    default:
        fatalError("Oops, this should not happen")
    }
}
```

I thought it might be similar to a problem I had in the past which involved trying to assign a `Measurement` to an optional but I don't have any optional values in this method so I assume I must be doing something else wrong.

LiftEvent:

```
extension LiftEvent {
    @NSManaged var date: Date
    @NSManaged var repetitions: NSNumber
    @NSManaged var uid: NSNumber?
    @NSManaged var weightLifted: NSNumber
    @NSManaged var weightUnit: String
    @NSManaged var formula: Formula
    @NSManaged var lift: Lift
}
```

The LiftEventRepresentable protocol is:

```
@objc protocol LiftEventRepresentable {
    var date: Date { get }
    var formula: Formula { get }
    var repetitions: NSNumber { get set }
    var liftWeight: Measurement<UnitMass> { get }
    var maxWeight: Double { get }
    var lift: Lift { get }
    var context: NSManagedObjectContext { get }
    var userDidChangeUnits: Bool { get set }

    func updateWeightLifted(_ weight: Double)
    func updateRepetitions(_ repetitions: Int)
    func updateMaxAmount(_ maxAmount: Measurement<UnitMass>) -> ()
    func updateLiftEventFormula(_ newFormulaUuid: String) -> ()
    func updateLift(_ newLiftUuid: String) -> ()
    func updateWeightUnit(_ newUnit: String)
    func calculateOneRepMax() -> Measurement<UnitMass>
    func updateLiftEventWithFinalValues()
}
```

Can anyone tell me why `liftEvent.liftWeight`is 0.0 lb after the conversion?

**EDIT 1**: This is how `liftEvent.liftWeight` is produced (which I should have included in my question originally). It's a computed property and I've now learning it's what causes the conversion to always return 0):

```
class LiftEvent: NSManagedObject, LiftEventRepresentable {

    var liftWeight: Measurement<UnitMass> {
        let defaultUnit = UserDefaults.weightUnit() // returns a string ("kg" or "lb")
        let unitSymbol = UnitMass.init(symbol: defaultUnit) // the wrong way
        let liftWeight = Measurement<UnitMass>(value: Double(weightLifted), unit: unitSymbol)
    return liftWeight
    }
```

**EDIT 2**: The root problem was, indeed, the liftEvent.liftWeight being invalid.

This is my new code which now works:

```
var liftWeight: Measurement<UnitMass> {
    let defaultUnit = UserDefaults.weightUnit() // returns a string ("kg" or "lb")
    let unit: UnitMass
    if defaultUnit == "kg" {
        unit = UnitMass.kilograms // the right way
        } else {
        unit = UnitMass.pounds // also the right way
    }
    let liftWeight = Measurement<UnitMass>(value: Double(weightLifted), unit: unit)
    return liftWeight
}
```

Comment: "Can anyone tell me" No, because you have elected not to show your actual code. Who knows what `liftEvent.liftWeight` really is? If it were, say, `Measurement(value: 110.0, unit: UnitMass.kilograms)`, this would work. Presumably, therefore, it isn't. But you have chosen to _hide_ from us what it _is_, so how can we help you?

Comment: Apologies, @matt, you are correct. I should have included the code showing what `liftEvent.liftWeight` really is. Upon further examination, I do have a bug that is causing `liftEvent.liftWeight` to not be a valid `Measurement`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Something is wrong with your `Measurement`'s unit. It's a `UnitMass` so it has the correct dimension, but its converter is missing. This is probably because you created it using something like `UnitMass(symbol: "kg")` instead of `UnitMass.kilograms`.

```
// right way
let goodUnit = UnitMass.kilograms
let goodWeight:Measurement = Measurement(value: 110.0, unit: goodUnit)
print("Good pounds: ", goodWeight.converted(to: .pounds)) // 242.508686220216 lb

// wrong way (results in 0.0 output)
let badUnit = UnitMass(symbol: "kg")
let badWeight:Measurement = Measurement(value: 110.0, unit: badUnit)
print("Bad pounds: ", badWeight.converted(to: .pounds)) // 0.0 lb
```

Creating a unit with `UnitMass(symbol: "kg")` is actually valid code, so there's no error. You can use this syntax to create your own mass units with any symbol you want and a custom converter. For some reason the `converter:` parameter is optional, so `UnitMass(symbol: "kg")` just makes a new mass unit with the symbol "kg" and a default `UnitLinearConverter` with a coefficient of 0.

Using `UnitMass.kilograms` instead gives you a predefined kilogram unit that's already setup with the correct symbol and converter. Easy mistake to make, especially since there's no error.

I recommend taking a look at where you create `liftEvent.liftWeight`, as that is likely where the problem lies.

Comment: I was certain it was a valid unit because when I printed `liftEvent.liftWeight.unit` in the console I saw `The unit is <NSUnitMass: 0x61000003e0e0> kg`. But I was creating it in a way that is essential the same as your "wrong way" example. I wonder why it didn't complain when I did it the wrong way.

Comment: @Jim but you still haven't shown your actual code by which you created `liftEvent.liftWeight`!

Comment: @Matt, there were votes to close the question so I didn't know if it was still appropriate to add it but I'm happy to. I will do so shortly.

Comment: It's the lack of relevant code that is _why_ there are votes to close the question. StackOverflow is about _showing_ your code, not _hiding_ it. — You still have not shown the _bad_ code that you were originally asking about! Please understand, I'm just trying to explain how to ask a good question on SO, no more. Really.

Comment: @matt, I understand and I'm not taking your comments negatively at all. Not only was I ultimately able to resolve my problem (and make my code more elegant based on your example) but I also learned the importance of not short cutting my questions and assuming people can figure out what's going on. I truly appreciate your help. I'll also take this opportunity to tell you that I think your books on Swift are simply the best a person could hope to find.